# Jython mouse listener on JLabel results in TypeError

Tags: swing, mouseevent, awt, jython

I'm making an application in Jython where I try to capture mouse events on a JLabel. I have a JFrame that contains a JLabel, but when I try to add a mouse listener to it I get:

```
TypeError: write only attribute
```

The main window:

```
class Commander(JFrame):
    ...
    self.image = ImageIcon()
    self.label = JLabel(self.image)
    self.mouseListener = ScreenMouseListener()
    self.label.addMouseListener(self.mouseListener) <- This line causes the TypeError
    ...
```

The mouse listener extends MouseAdapter:

```
class ScreenMouseListener(MouseAdapter):
    def mousePressed(self, event):
        print "Mouse pressed"
```

Searching for the error leads me to [PyBeanEvent](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/python/jython/2.2/jython-2.2-sources.jar!/org/python/core/PyBeanEvent.java?format=ok), but I don't understand why it happens. Which attribute is write-only?

**Edit:** After removing the line that caused the error, I noticed that the mousePressed function gets called! Is "mouseListener" perhaps a property of JFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe JFrame.mouseListener is a write-only property, i.e. there is no get function implemented, so when it was passed to self.label.addMouseListener, it could not be read.
Solved it by doing the following instead:

```
self.label.addMouseListener(ScreenMouseListener())
```